# sql query to join two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables(mysql), one for product name and other for product images.

> tblproducts --> id(int,pk), name(varchar)
>
> tblphotos ---> id(int,pk), productid(int,fk), photo, order

in tblphotos the order field is the display order of the photos (1,2,3...)

There can be more than 1 photo for each product. I need the first photo of the product(order =1)

I need is tblproducts.id,tblproducts.name,tblphotos.photo(photo must be the one with order 1)

I wrote the following query,but I am product name is repeating

```
   SELECT tblproducts.id,tblproducts.name, tblphotos.photo 
     FROM tblproducts 
LEFT JOIN tblphotos on tblphotos.productid = tblproducts.id
```

one more thing :: I need to sort the order in ascending order

Comment: You forgot using where clause? ie; where 'tblphotos.order=1'

Answer (score 3):

If you only want the first photo (the one with order = 1) then you need to specify that in your query:

```
SELECT
    PR.id AS product_id,
    PR.name,
    PH.photo
FROM
    Products PR
LEFT OUTER JOIN Photos PH ON
    PH.product_id = PR.id AND
    PH.`order` = 1
```

Since `order` is likely a reserved word, I've enclosed it in the default quoted identifier for MySQL. You'd be better off with a different column name though. Also, I can't bring myself to write a query with "tbl" in front of table names.

Comment: @JohnK, have to agree with TomH that you should stay away from reserved words in your column names - it will only cause you problems down the line and also not necessary to prefix table names with tbl.  Still on a standards point, the table names should usually be singular i.e. product and photo rather than plural but it's a minor point.

Comment: +1. @JohnK: `SortOrder` is a good alternative to `Order`. Another one is `Sort`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT tblproducts.id,tblproducts.name, tblphotos.photo 
FROM tblproducts LEFT JOIN tblphotos on tblphotos.productid = tblproducts.id 
and tblphotos.order=1
```

Answer (score -1):

i think this will work for you

```
SELECT tblproducts.id, tblproducts.name, tblphotos.photo 
FROM tblproducts 
LEFT JOIN tblphotos on tblphotos.productid = tblproducts.id
   and tblphotos.order=1;
```

Comment: I believe that `and` must be chnage with `where`. `and` will apply only on the  `tblphotos`. This means that **all** rows from `tblproducts`  will still be there and if they lost a match in `tblphotos` because of `end` this will be replaced by null values.

Comment: @Melsi:Yeah i think you are right all the data from tblproducts will be in result...we can also replace the LEFT JOIN with JOIN then it should be correct.